# Elan Smart pad disables itself

Tags: touchpad

I have a very bizarre problem.
I have a laptop running Windows 10 pro, with an Elan Smart Pad. The problem is that it would disable itself in a seemingly random pattern. I got around it by navigating to the elan settings via keyboard,  but that takes a lot of time and is very annoying. Today however,  I discovered that the trigger disabling it was my laptop charger. When I unplugged it,  the touchpad would become disabled and would become enabled again when I plug the laptop back in. Weird.

Comment: Welcome!  What kind of laptop is it (make/model)?  Have you tried updating the touchpad's driver to the latest version?

Comment: This sounds like a driver problem.  Your touchpad in my experience does not have Windows 10 drivers or if they do they are not supplied directly by Elan.

Comment: It's a relatively obscure laptop company. The brand sticker on the laptop is Nobilis but it is also associated with the company Equus. Which sells computers for businesses. I got this computer from a small business that wasn't using it. All drivers are up to date according to Windows. And Equus doesn't have windows 10 driver downloads.

Comment: Sounds like you have a notebook that is simply not Windows 10 compatible. I'd pick up the phone and call Equus and ask them for some help/advice/driver. :)

Comment: Thanks. I guess I have some phone calls to make then. I'm impressed with the reply speed here. I'll update this post after I contact them.

Comment: Not that I have any experience with Win10 at this point, but if not a bug or driver issue, it crosses my mind that this might be some weird power-saving feature?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emailed the laptop company with the serial number, and they replied with a link to a product page on the msi website with a computer that looked like mine. I never would have found it myself. Downloaded the driver and all seems to be working now. Guess I just had to ask.